# Container on VM with Docker and Kubernetes Cluster Orchestration

Tags: docker, kubernetes, virtual-machine

I can understand basic management and operation of container on bare-metal running Docker engine and Kubernetes Orchestration. I'm wondering how is the management and orchestration of container on virtual machine (VM)? Anyone familiar working of container on VM, does it difficult to manage and orchestrate compare to container on bare-metal?

1. Resources of container on VM as my understanding the VM instance itself is already mapped to specific flavor (e.g 2vCPU and 8G memory) and does it means if container on VM will be limited by the defined VM flavor?
2. How K8s will manage container on VM, does it see the VM as a VM or as a POD?

Thanks for sharing your comments and input. Please advise and enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference if you are looking forward to using **VM** as **worker node** of the **Kubernetes** cluster and manage the POD (container) over it. Kubernetes consider and manage the VM as Node.

If you are looking forward to running standalone containers on top of a **VM** using simple **docker** without any **Orchestration** tool, it will be hard to manage

- Deployment options
- Scaling containers
- Resource management
- Load balancing the traffic across containers
- Handling the routing
- Monitor the health of containers and hosts

If you are still looking forward to running the container top of **only VM** there are few managed services from **AWS & GCP**.

- **Cloud Run**
- **ECS**

above are managed container Orchestration services and using it you can manage the container top of **VM**.

If you looking forward to the running the container by your ownself on simple you can do it using simple **docker** or **docker-compose** also. But at very first you will face an issue routing the traffic across multiple containers.

> How K8s will manage container on VM, does it see the VM as a VM or as
> a POD?

It sees the VM as a node and runs the necessary services top of VM first and manages it.

Comment: From your explanation...VM is a worker node and contains container over it. From the perspective of K8s it sees as node. As I understand a POD is always run on a Node, does POD 'term' still valid in Container over VM case? By the way I'm thinking to run with MANO solution.

Comment: Container run inside Pod now if you are running just container using docker top of VM POD won’t exist anywhere unless and until you are using K8s. Or else pod won’t come in picture. For understanding you can consider pod as container but in reality there is difference as Container run inside pod.

Comment: Thanks for your good explanation. At least It did clear me something.... Thank you.